# Makefile variable to hold a rule

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to employ the `ALSO` option detailed in [this table](https://gitlab.com/bztsrc/posix-uefi#available-makefile-options), which is then called as such:

```
all: $(ALLTARGETS) $(EXTRA) $(ALSO)
```

For this reason I suspect that to make this work I have to somehow put a rule inside a variable.

Tries so far:

```
ALSO = " echo I didn't make it!"
ALSO = " \n \ 
         echo I didn't make it!"
ALSO = "myrule: \n\
         echo I didn't make it!"
```

How should I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was over complicating, just store the name of your rule:

```
ALSO = myrule

myrule: 
        echo I made it!
```

Nonetheless, is there anyway to do what I was originally trying to accomplish? Maybe to dynamically create rules?

Comment: There are multiple ways.  You might find the following series of blog posts enlightening: http://make.mad-scientist.net/category/metaprogramming/ (read them from the bottom up)